# Reducing the spacial resolution using the nearest-neighbor resampling formula in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, nearest-neighbor

I am attempting to write a function in matlab that will return an image reduced to the size `MS` = length x-resolution in pixels in original image and `NS`= length of y-resolution in original image  using the nearest neighbor formula.

I am getting an out of bounds exception and am having a bit of difficulty identifying a solution.. I assume I need another conditional check.  Currently, for my image, it is attempting to access `d(1309,27)`, however it shouldn't access that value as it is bounded `M` and `N` within the for loop: `for ms = 1:M`

```
     function  r  = imaging( s, M, N, L )
     %imaging Computes the acquisition of the image
         s= imread('Z:\file.tif');
         figure, imshow(s);


         d = im2double(s);

         [MS, NS] = size(d);

         M = 400;
         N = 100;

         dx = M/MS;
         dy = N/NS;

         for ms = 1:M
            mp= floor( (ms +0.5)/dx ) ;
               for ns = 1:N
                  if(d(ms,ns))
                  np= floor( (ns +0.5)/dy ) ;
                  r(ms,ns)= d(mp,np);
               end
         end
    end
```

Comment: Why not use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/imresize.html)?

Comment: I am essentially learning the functioning behind imresize.  It was given as an assignment so I am not looking for the working solution but rather a helping hand towards a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your nearest-neighbour resizing is not to scale. If it is to scale, you should use the **imresize** function to simplify your life. If it is not to scale, you should make a lookup table for your indices using the following code.

```
round( linspace( 1, MS, M ) )
```

The index represents the final image index. The output represents the index it should look for in the original image. This is for the M case, and the same can be said for the N case. Your final code should be as follows. Tested and works as follows.

```
% Image init
s = imread( 'bag.png' );
figure; imshow( s );
d = im2double( s );

% Get sizes
[MS, NS] = size( d );
M = 400;
N = 100;

% Create image
r = zeros( M, N );

% Create table lookup
lookupM = round( linspace( 1, MS, M ) );
lookupN = round( linspace( 1, NS, N ) );

% Assign New R
for ms = 1:M
    for ns = 1:N
        r(ms,ns) = d( lookupM( ms ), lookupN( ns ) );
    end
end

% Display output
figure; imshow(r);
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I'm still new to posting StackOverflow responses.

EDIT: Used linspace function instead of interp1 function

Comment: @codeDaily My stupid rep amount doesn't let me comment on your post, but if you need help, just ask me. I feel my code is sufficiently self explanatory and I'm desperate for rep points lol...